# Как удалить часть значений категориальной переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, структуры-данных, pandas

Данные выглядят так:

```
merged4_new['pgfamstd']
Out[57]: 
0              [1] verheiratet zus.
1              [1] verheiratet zus.
2              [1] verheiratet zus.
3              [1] verheiratet zus.
                      ...
470702                    [3] ledig
470703         [1] verheiratet zus.
470704                    [3] ledig
470705         [1] verheiratet zus.
470706                    [3] ledig
```

Посмотрев на распределение я хочу удалить некоторые значения переменной:

```
merged4_new['pgfamstd'].value_counts()
Out[66]: 
[1] verheiratet zus.         289419
[3] ledig                    108685
[4] geschieden                27042
[5] verwitwet                 26310
[2] verheiratet getr.          7887
[6] Ehepartner im Ausland       825
-1.0                             21
-3.0                             10
Name: pgfamstd, dtype: int64
```

А Именно значения [6] Ehepartner im Ausland, -1.0, -3.0.
Пока я смог это сделать только используя `LabelEncoder` из `sklearn.preprocessing` присвоив новые значения переменной `pgfamstd`, и тогда с числовыми значениями для неё мы можем избавиться от отрицательных значений используя `merged4_new = merged4[merged4['pgfamstd']>1]` команду. Но тогда значения переменной присвоенные ранее теряют последовательность и остаётся только ряд разбросанных категорий. Например вместо ранжировки 012345 остаётся 1345.

Я хотел использовать маску или отбор данных, с использованием логического И `&`, в начале, чтобы с самого начала удалить часть значений из переменной. Но получал ошибку.

Как мне удалить часть переменной, чтобы структура присвоенных числовых значений категориям переменной в последующем оставалась целостной?

```
merged4_new['pgfamstd'].dtype
Out[67]: dtype('O')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

все это достаточно легко делается средствами pandas:

```
In [46]: df
Out[46]:
                     pgfamstd
0        [1] verheiratet zus.
1                        -3.0
2   [6] Ehepartner im Ausland
3       [2] verheiratet getr.
4                   [3] ledig
5                        -1.0
6              [4] geschieden
7        [1] verheiratet zus.
8                        -3.0
9                        -1.0
10       [1] verheiratet zus.
11  [6] Ehepartner im Ausland
12             [4] geschieden
13                  [3] ledig
14                       -1.0
15                  [3] ledig
16              [5] verwitwet
17  [6] Ehepartner im Ausland
18                       -3.0
19             [4] geschieden
20      [2] verheiratet getr.
21              [5] verwitwet
22      [2] verheiratet getr.
23              [5] verwitwet

In [47]: vals_2_drop = ['[6] Ehepartner im Ausland','-1.0','-3.0']

In [50]: df = df[~df.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop)]

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
                 pgfamstd
0    [1] verheiratet zus.
3   [2] verheiratet getr.
4               [3] ledig
6          [4] geschieden
7    [1] verheiratet zus.
10   [1] verheiratet zus.
12         [4] geschieden
13              [3] ledig
15              [3] ledig
16          [5] verwitwet
19         [4] geschieden
20  [2] verheiratet getr.
21          [5] verwitwet
22  [2] verheiratet getr.
23          [5] verwitwet
```

Пошагово:

```
In [49]: df.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop)
Out[49]:
0     False
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10    False
11     True
12    False
13    False
14     True
15    False
16    False
17     True
18     True
19    False
20    False
21    False
22    False
23    False
Name: pgfamstd, dtype: bool

In [48]: df[~df.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop)]
Out[48]:
                 pgfamstd
0    [1] verheiratet zus.
3   [2] verheiratet getr.
4               [3] ledig
6          [4] geschieden
7    [1] verheiratet zus.
10   [1] verheiratet zus.
12         [4] geschieden
13              [3] ledig
15              [3] ledig
16          [5] verwitwet
19         [4] geschieden
20  [2] verheiratet getr.
21          [5] verwitwet
22  [2] verheiratet getr.
23          [5] verwitwet
```

Comment: MaxU, а если после удаления переменной посчитать распределения функцией `.value_counts()` у вас поменяются значения? после проверки кода, значения этой команды остались прежними, но если написать условие `if X.any()==True:...`, то окажется что значений: _'[6] Ehepartner im Ausland','-1.0','-3.0'_ больше нет.
Знак ~ означает: не?

Comment: @user21, я просто удалил все строки содержащие `['[6] Ehepartner im Ausland','-1.0','-3.0']`. `value_counts()` для остальных значений не должно поменяться. `~` - операция логического отрицания, т.е. `df[~df.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop)]` - вернет только те строки где `pgfamstd` НЕ одно из значений входящих в `vals_2_drop` (другими словами ВСЕ КРОМЕ значений из `vals_2_drop`)

Comment: Спасибо, но я имел в виду не остальные значения а те которые должны были быть удалены.

    `merged4['pgfamstd'].value_counts()
    Out[5]: 
    [1] verheiratet zus.     293703
    [3] ledig                113596
    [4] geschieden            27577
    [5] verwitwet             26871
    [2] verheiratet getr.      8058
    -2.0                         40
    -1.0                         23
    -3.0                         10`

Comment: @user21, я не совсем понимаю - можете объяснить? Вы хотите поменять значения, но НЕ удалять строки? Тогда поясните на какие значения вы хотите поменять: `['[6] Ehepartner im Ausland','-1.0','-3.0']`

Comment: Я адаптировал код, но возможно что-то не так. Мы создаём список значений которые необходимо убрать: `vals_2_drop = ['[6] Ehepartner im Ausland','-1.0','-3.0', '-2.0']`. Заменяем дата сет на новый (с удалёнными переменными): `merged4 = merged4[~merged4.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop)]`. В Вашем случае (df).

Comment: Затем я хочу снова посмотреть на распределение переменной: `merged4['pgfamstd'].value_counts()` и эта функция показывает что значения которые должны были быть удалены всё ещё там, но команда  `merged4.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop).sum()`  все значения в списке были удалены т.к. я получаю 0.

Comment: Получается что две функции указывают на противоположный результат. Хотя мне кажется ошибка в замене дата сета. Как вы думаете MaxU?

Comment: @user21, были ли какие-либо предупреждения (warnings) при `merged4 = merged4[~merged4.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop)]`? Вы уверены, что `vals_2_drop` - содержит именно те значения, которые вы хотите удалить (т.е. те, которые не должны присутствовать в `merged4['pgfamstd'].value_counts()`)?

Comment: Нет команды исполнились чисто. Да именно эти значения: [6] Ehepartner im Ausland - не интересна из за малого объёма данных, остальные -1.0, -3.0, не располагают какой-либо информативностью.

Comment: @user21, хммм..., просто загадка. Я не знаю как такое воспроизвести... Когда я пробую с тестовыми данными - все работает правильно

Comment: Я загружу с самого начала данные и попробую ещё раз. Если снова получатся разные результаты, я напишу. Но по факту этих данных уже нет в дата сете. Вопрос пока почему `merged4['pgfamstd'].value_counts()` выдаёт такие результаты у меня. Спасибо!

Comment: Я попробовал и оказалось что нужно было кавычки убрать перед числами в списке на удаление: `vals_2_drop = ['[6] Ehepartner im Ausland','-1.0','-3.0']` -> `vals_2_drop = ['[6] Ehepartner im Ausland',-1.0, -3.0]`. Но всё равно предупреждение какое-то было : `merged4_new2 = merged4_new[~merged4.pgfamstd.isin(vals_2_drop1)]
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1997: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  "DataFrame index.", UserWarning)`